# How do i remove a FALSE result form a nested if statement

Tags: excel-formula

Can someone help me edit this formula to not return FALSE if criteria not met?

=IF(C24="No",IF(G9>=250000,(((G9-100000)/1000)*5)+575),IF(C24="Yes",IF(G9>=250000,((((G9-100000)/1000)*5)+575),"")))

I can't seem to get the syntax correct :(

Answer (score 0):

Break your formula down into indented rows, so you see where the elements start and end.

```
=IF(C24="No",
   IF(G9>=250000, // condition
      (((G9-100000)/1000)*5)+575 // true
      // false missing
   ),
   IF(C24="Yes", 
      IF(G9>=250000, //condition
         ((((G9-100000)/1000)*5)+575), // true
         "" // false
      )
   // false missing
   )
)
```

Now you can see the conditions, true, and false statement in their own lines.

The first nested IF does not have a FALSE statement, so if G9 is not >= 250000, the default "FALSE" will be returned. Here is where you need to put in what you would like to see instead.

The IF statement that tests C24 for "yes" also does not have a False statement, but assuming that C24 is either Yes or No, that will not matter at this stage.